# Navigating to a project document from a LinkButton

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get an excel file to popup on a page in a new window when a user clicks an asp:linkbutton on a webform. I am setting it up to use the OnClick function and in the code behind I do a respond.redirect to the location of the excel file in the project. You can see this in the code below. For some reason it is not working, I get a blank page that pops up in my browser. Is this even best practices? I could also direct the link to shared network drive where there excel files can be stored but that just seems a little too complicated.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCBFormat" runat="server" Text="CB Format Example" OnClick="btnCBFormat_Click" Target="_blank" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMBFormat" runat="server" Text="MB Format Example" OnClick="btnMBFormat_Click" Target="_blank" />

        protected void btnCBFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("//Chargebacks/Formats/CBFormat.xsl");
        }

        protected void btnMBFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("//Chargebacks/Formats/MBFormat.xls");
        }
```

Comment: Why not just have a straight-forward `<a>` link to the Excel files? Why is using a postback link necessary?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think Dai is right:  you should use a `<a>` link to the Excel files, not a postback.

Second, I suspect the problem you're having has to do with IIS not being set up to serve Excel files.  You're telling it to load something that it doesn't know how to return.

And that's as it should be.  If you have to postback for other reasons and need to stream the Excel to your users, research streaming files to the user via ASP.NET.  That's how it's usually done.

Incidentally, if those Excel files are going to be updated on an ongoing basis, putting them on a file share makes sense:  you'll be able to modify them without fiddling with your web server.